# Why does Math.pow(1, Infinity) return NaN?

Tags: javascript

I always thought any power of 1 equals 1, but `Math.pow(1, Infinity)` returns NaN. Why not 1?

Comment: It's the way the Javascript gods wanted it to be

Comment: Not just JavaScript. That's how the math is defined.

Comment: actually, I expect it's the way the IEEE754 gods defined it to be...

Comment: Yep. Math gods > Javascript gods :P

Comment: ("Math gods" are theoretical. "IEEE-754 gods" are practical. JavaScript is a practical implementation which *specifically follows IEEE-754* binary64. Although, I am not sure how if `pow` is itself is technically covered by IEEE-754 even if `NaN` is.)

Comment: Actually, this behavior of `pow` *is defined* in IEEE-754 2008 (it also defines it in relation to qNaN), however, to find an actually IEEE-754 reference is .. not easy. Also, different programming languages (e.g. C and Java) differ on their implementations/requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more of a math question than a Javascript question, and you therefore use mathematical explanations such as the following ([http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53372.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20171203230155/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53372.html)):

> When you have something like "infinity," you have to realize that it's
> not a number. Usually what you mean is some kind of limiting process.
> So if you have "1^infinity" what you really have is some kind of limit:
> the base isn't really 1, but is getting closer and closer to 1 perhaps
> while the exponent is getting bigger and bigger, like maybe (x+1)^(1/x)
> as x->0+.

> The question is, which is happening faster, the base getting close to
> 1 or the exponent getting big? To find out, let's call:

> L = lim x->0 of (x+1)^(1/x)

> Then:

> ln L = lim x->0 of (1/x) ln (x+1) = lim x->0 of ln(x+1) / x

> So what's that? As x->0 it's of 0/0 form, so take the derivative of the
> top and bottom. Then we get lim x->0 of 1/(x+1) / 1, which = 1.
> So ln L = 1, and L = e. Cool!

> Is it really true? Try plugging in a big value of x. Or recognize this
> limit as a variation of the definition of e. Either way, it's true. The
> limit is of the 1^infinity form, but in this case it's e, not 1. Try
> repeating the work with (2/x) in the exponent, or with (1/x^2), or with
> 1/(sqrt(x)), and see how that changes the answer.

> That's why we call it indeterminate - all those different versions of
> the limit approach 1^infinity, but the final answer could be any
> number, such as 1, or infinity, or undefined. You need to do more work
> to determine the answer, so 1^infinity by itself is not determined yet.
> In other words, 1 is just one of the answers of 1^infinity.

An answer of "indeterminate" is not a number.

Comment: You are calculating `lim_{x->1,y->∞}(x^y) = (1)^(∞)`, which is indeterminate. But `lim_{y->∞}(1^y) = 1^(∞) = 1`

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319764/1-to-the-power-of-infinity-why-is-it-indeterminate?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Particularly for JS it is defined in the standard, [ECMAScript-262 5th Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), page 163:

> If abs(x)==1 and y is +∞, the result is NaN

The reason is that infinity only makes sense with limits.

So

```
lim 1^x -> ∞
x->∞
```

but the `1^∞` is undefined (for programming languages. For math it is defined and expressed as a limit)

Comment: The limit would be written as lim 1^x where x approaches infinity. Your math is bad. Unity to any finite power is certainly well defined and the Cauchy sequence would define the limit as exactly one as expected.

Comment: @shawnt00: actually I was waiting for this comment :-) I could try to write it in a right way, but I don't know the readable form for correct format. On paper it's easy, but not here

Comment: I'm not making a minor point about notation. Your reasoning is simply wrong.

Comment: @shawnt00: does it make sense now?

Comment: @shawnt00: well, from math point of view - it is incorrect, but in js you cannot express result as a limit

Comment: Well if `1 ^ x = 1` for any `x`, it would follow that it would still hold if `x = ±inf`

Comment: @lanzz: for math it's not true, why should it be true for js?

Comment: @lanzz: `If abs(x)==1 and y is +∞, the result is NaN`, page 163 of your link

Answer (score 1):

The IEEE 754-2008 defines:
`1^(+-)Inf = +1`

The language you use does not comfort to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

jeff`s answer is good, but it says:

> When you have something like "infinity," you have to realize that it's
>   not a number. Usually what you mean is some kind of limiting process.
>   So if you have "1^infinity" what you really have is some kind of
>   limit: the base isn't really 1, but is getting closer and closer to 1
>   perhaps while the exponent is getting bigger and bigger, like maybe
>   (x+1)^(1/x) as x->0+.

Well, if you have `1^∞`, of course the exponent can't be exactly `∞`, because it isn't a real number. But the base can be EXACTLY 1 all the time.

Then,

```
lim   (x^y) = (1)^(∞) = ?? undefined ??
x->1
y->∞
```

But

```
lim  (1^y) = 1^(∞) = 1
y->∞
```

(The parenthesis notation means that the part inside the parenthesis is a sequence that converges to that number, but it isn't that number)

Then, I think that if Javascript had an integrer type, `Math.pow( (int)1, Infinity)` should give `1`.

But the fact is that (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605946/1529630)

> All numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit floating point numbers.

Then, (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), since IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point numbers have a significand of 53 bits (52 explicitly stored),

> The total precision is therefore 53 bits (approximately 16 decimal digits, 53 log10(2) ≈ 15.955)

So when we do `Math.pow(1,Infinity)`, that `1` isn't EXACTLY 1.

Then, it makes sense that `Math.pow(1,Infinity)` is `NaN`

Comment: Huh? IEEE 754 `1` *is* exactly 1.

Comment: @Bergi I meant that since there are precision errors, a number stored as 1 isn't always the mathematical idea of 1