# Combining 8 high bits and 8 low bits in javascript

Tags: javascript, node-red, 16-bit, 8-bit

I'm sending a water depth in mm to my NodeRed server where I'm currently attempting to reconstruct a 16-bit Int that has been split into 8 high bits and 8 low bits.

I've tried just storing the high bits in a var and shifting them left 8 spaces and then adding the low bits to the variable by OR'ing the two but I've had no success.

I saw somewhere someone suggested trying this

```
var _firstNumber = (((number8Bit2 & 0xff) << 8) | (number8Bit1 & 0xff));
```

Any suggestions friends?

Here is the node red function

```
msg1 = {};
msg2 = {};

var buf1 = msg.payload.slice(0,1);
var buf2 = msg.payload.slice(1, 2);

var lvl = (((buf2 & 0xff) << 8) | (buf1 & 0xff));

var buf3 = msg.payload.slice(2,3);
var batt = buf3.readUInt8();

batt = (batt + 127)/100;

msg1.payload = lvl;
msg1.topic = 'waterlevel';
msg2.payload = batt;
msg2.topic = 'battery';

return [msg1, msg2];
```

Comment: I don't know how this would work.  [JavaScript stores all numbers in IEEE-754 floating-point format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605925/does-javascript-have-double-floating-point-number-precision), using 8 bytes.

Comment: @Amy - `&` and `<<` etc result in 32 bit "integers" (though they are still numbers of course)

Comment: Ahh that's unfortunate, I have the opportunity to decode it before arrival in TheThingsNetwork however the packet decoders are in Javascript also.. Thanks Amy!

Comment: Hm, I didn't know this.  [operands of bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Comment: `I saw somewhere someone suggested trying this ... Any suggestions friends?` I suggest you try the suggested code because it looks correct - I mean, **have** you even tried?

Comment: `but I've had no success` - what happened? was the result wrong? what was the input values? what was the result you got? what was the result you expected? Details of your failure may help us determine how you failed

Comment: Yeah of course I've tried but the result is 256 when it should be 300 so there's an overflow. I'll post my node red function if I can get the tags to work

Comment: yeah, code in comments is **unreadable** ... `256` is NOT an overflow ... what was the input bytes ... `number8Bit1 === 44` and `number8Bit2 === 1`?

Comment: `number8Bit2 *256 + number8Bit1`   should work if input was converted correctly.

Comment: The payload is FF 31 E4 however E4 is the battery level

Comment: how do you convert the payload to javascript variables?

Comment: is msg.payload an `UInt8Array`?

Comment: by the way FF 31 would be 49 * 256 + 255 ... so, nothing like 256 or 300

Comment: I've updated my initial post with the function from NodeRed, the low bits are buf1 and the high buf2

Comment: it looks like `buf1` and `buf2` are both a unit-length [`TypedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray), not numbers.

Comment: The other important question is probably, is the value Little endian or Big endian?

Comment: Edit the question to show the actual input and it's format. Namely how are you receiving the data (MQTT, serial) and is it arriving as a buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually have a buffer, and not a string... It depends on big-endian/little-endian, but you can do something like the following:

```
const buffer = Buffer.from([0xFF, 0x31, 0xE4]);
const readInt16BE = buffer.readInt16BE(0);
const readInt16LE = buffer.readInt16LE(0);

msg.payload = {
    buffer: buffer,
    readInt16BE: readInt16BE,
    readInt16LE: readInt16LE
}

return msg;
```